# Get Access Token from connected app in case of SSO user

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps

I need to get an access token from the connected app, but the problem is that the user does not have a username and password it logs in via SSO.

And for fetching connected app I use Password grant_type.

Comment: The user is already logged in and has a token. What are you trying to accomplish? See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @identigral, I want to fetch the token from the connected app for hitting some APIs.I am not talking about the UI token